# BreezeJS WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table2)

Tags: breeze

How do I write in BreezeJS to achieve something like this in MySQL?

```
SELECT id
FROM table1
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM table2
)
```

I just couldn't figure it out other than breaking this in to 2 separate BreezeJS queries and do a double for loop on the result arrays to get rid of the duplicates.

Comment: Look at the breeze docs for `any`  and `all` queries